# Pulling remote 'client uploaded assets' into a local website development environment

Tags: web, local, assets

This is an issue we come up against again and again, how to get live website assets uploaded by a client into the local development environment. The options are:

1. Download all the things (can be a lengthy process and has to be repeated often)
2. Write some insane script that automates #1
3. Some uber clever thing which maps a local folder to a remote URL

I would really love to know how to achieve #3, have some kind of alias/folder in my local environment which is ignored by Git but means that when testing changes locally I will see client uploaded assets where they should be rather than broken images (and/or other things).

I do wonder if this might be possible using Panic Transmit and the 'Transmit disk' feature.

*Update*

Ok thus far I have managed to get a remote server folder mapped to my local machine as a drive (of sorts) using the '[Web Disk](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/WebDisk)' option in cPanel and then the 'Connect to server' option in OS X.

However although I can then browse the folder contents in a safe read only fashion on my local machine when I alias that drive to a folder in /sites Apache just prompts me to download the alias file rather that follow it as a symlink might... :/

Answer (score 3):

KISS: I'd go with #2.

I usally put a small script like `update_assets.sh` in the project's folder which uses `rsync` to download the files:

```
rsync --recursive --stats --progress -aze user@site.net:~/path/to/remote/files local/path
```

I wouldn't call that insane :) I prefer to have all the files locally so that I can work with them when I'm offline or on a slow connection.

`rsync` is quite fast and maybe you also want to check out the `--delete` flag to delete local files when they were removed from remote.

Comment: Thanks Nils, I'm going to give that a shot though I'm not going to mark it as 'THE ANSWER' because it means having a copy of all the files on my local filesystem which feels ALL WRONG! ;)

Comment: I use that only in a couple of projects. Most of the time my local project is independent so it has its own DB and therefore also assets. Of course you can exclude some folders or files that are larger than eg 1.5MB: `--max-size=1.5m`. I prefer my local system to work independently as much as possible (which includes offline).